# Windows server 2000 installation on vSphere 5.1 (VMware esxi 5.1)

Tags: windows, esxi, windows-server, windows-server-2000

When creating a new virtual machine on vSphere 5.1 (VMware esxi 5.1) it asks for the version of guest operating system i'm going to install. But in the drop down menu they provide Windows Server 2000 is not available. Supported OS are show in the screenshot attached below.

[image]

Can some one please tell me which one to select when installing Windows Server 2000. Thanks!

Comment: Try Windows 2000 and see if it works; as far as I remember, this works for either Workstation or Server versions.

Comment: @Renan Ok. I will try.